# Magento 2:How get price configurable in product list

Tags: attributes, magento2, configurable-product, price

How can get price product

With simple product:
`$oldPrice= $_product->getPrice();
$newPrice= $_product->getSpecialPrice();`
it returns the right results
With configuable product:
`$oldPrice= $_product->getPrice(); //return Null
$newPrice= $_product->getSpecialPrice(); // return Null`
I have 1 configuable product and 2 simple products
TestCon1
 Simple1: Price 120$. Special price: 100$
 simple2: Price 120$. Special price: 90$

I need get  price of configuable return: TestCon1 Price 120$. Special price: 90$.

i use `$oldpriceConf= $_product->getFinalPrice(); // retunr 100$`

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: How to get the price of the child product

Answer (score 3):

Configurable products don't have any regular price or special price.
On front end the price of their child product is taken as their regular price.

Comment: Yes! i know! Can you help me get price simple product of configurable(Magento 2 is new). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this for configurable product prices:

Regular price:

```
$oldPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
```

Final price:

```
$finalPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this file in Magento 2:

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php
```

It contains 2 methods that you can paste into your block:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getPriceRender();

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'include_container' => true,
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                'list_category_page' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}

/**
 * Specifies that price rendering should be done for the list of products
 * i.e. rendering happens in the scope of product list, but not single product
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render
 */
protected function getPriceRender()
{
    return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default')
                ->setData('is_product_list', true);
}
```

Use like so in your .phtml template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getProductPrice($product); ?>
```

This works well to display preformatted price and sale price with crossed out old price.

[image]